# CSS columns - decreasing font size and scrollWidth reaction in WebKit

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I have multi column (css3 webkit columns with fixed heights) layout in my document. When I increase font sizes for elements (using element.style.setProperty('font-size', ...); my body.scrollWidth increases also and this is OK. However, wehn decreasing font size body.scrollWidth stays the same and I'm left with a lot of blank space on the far right.

Any thoughts how I can solve this problem? How to force body.scrollWidth to reflect the changes to the document and shrink when necessary?

Comment: why don't you use `element.style.fontSize = '...';`?

Comment: sorry, it was element.style.setProperty('font-size', ...); using element.style.fontSize doesn't help